# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file but there is no error

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, php

This is my php code of index.php of a wordpress theme:

```
<section id="content">
    <?php
        $i=1;
        while(have_posts() && i < 7):the_post();
        $tumbUrl = '';
        if(has_post_thumbnail())
        {
            $tumbUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        }
        if(i < 4):
    ?>
    <div id="row1">
        <div id="tile<?echo $i?>" class="tile">
            <div id="img<?echo $i?>" class="tileimage"<?if($tumbUrl != ''):?> style="background-image:<?echo $tumbUrl; ?>"<?endif;?>></div>
            <div id="text<?echo $i?>" class="tiletext"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?
        else:
    ?>
    <div id="row2">
        <div id="tile<?echo $i?>" class="tile">
            <div id="img<?echo $i?>" class="tileimage"<?if($tumbUrl != ''):?> style="background-image:<?echo $tumbUrl; ?>"<?endif;?>></div>
            <div id="text<?echo $i?>" class="tiletext"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?
        endif;
        endwhile;
    ?>
</section>
```

and when I want to run it I get the error saying that `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\Odatis\index.php on line 31` but I cann't find any error.

Can anybody help me?

(my PHP version is 5.4.3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its very simple. You use short open tags `<?`.

Enable the short open tags in your **php.ini** or use the complete php tags like `<?php` in newer PHP-Versions its disabled by default. But you shouldn't use the short syntax in your projects that can cause Problems if you share your code.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: `short_open_tag = ON` but the error is same! (it was `OFF` and I changed it to `ON`)

Comment: "in newer PHP-Versions its disabled as default" - what?

Comment: Normally there are is more then one value in your php.ini. Search for a second value.

Comment: @Jueecy look at my link ;) PHP_INI_ALL in PHP <= 4.0.0. PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP < 5.3.0 in PHP 5.4 normally short open tags are disabled.

Comment: the first one was comment and there were just two `short_open_tag`.

Comment: And what is when you replace the short open tags? Is it working after the change? (check it with a phpinfo wheather its really enabled)

Comment: @Stony, where is it that it says that in PHP 5.4 short tags are disabled?

Comment: @Jueecy Sorry in Windows its disabled. In all Windows versions i know the short open tags are disabled in newer versions. But it was disabled in his php.ini so normally it should work when its enabled.

Comment: I changed `short_open_tag = Off` to `short_open_tag = On` but that didn't worked. Now I changed every `<?` to `<?php` and that worked!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the modified working code...

```
<section id="content">
    <?php 
        $i=1;
        while(have_posts() && i < 7):the_post();
        $tumbUrl = '';
        if(has_post_thumbnail())
        {
            $tumbUrl = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        }
        if(i < 4):
    ?>
    <div id="row1">
        <div id="tile<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tile">
            <div id="img<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tileimage"<?php if($tumbUrl != ''): ?> style="background-image:<?php echo $tumbUrl; ?>"<?php endif; ?>></div>
            <div id="text<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tiletext"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        else:
    ?>
    <div id="row2">
        <div id="tile<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tile">
            <div id="img<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tileimage"<?php if($tumbUrl != ''): ?> style="background-image:<?php echo $tumbUrl; ?>"<?php endif; ?>></div>
            <div id="text<?php echo $i; ?>" class="tiletext"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="a<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        endif;
        endwhile;
    ?>
</section>
```

```
Note: Make sure the ending mark(;) are there and also the space as required.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace all `<?echo ###?>` with `<?= ### ?>`. Or you need to enable the short open tags in your php.ini if your PHP is < 5.4.

**aww no: There is a semicolon missing in `<?php the_permalink() ?>`**

One of these should fix it, otherwise I'm sorry :/

Comment: Did you see my edit? There are 2 semicolons missing at `the_permalink()`